# R chunk inside LaTeX in an rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to get an R chunk run inside LaTeX code in the following rmarkdown document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-05-20'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
{
```{r}
x <- 2+3
x
```
}
\end{enumerate}
````

The output is:

[image]

But I want:

[image]

Could you please help me?

**EDIT:** I want the R chunk to be both evaluated (but result hidden) and its code shown. I have meanwhile found this solution, but maybe there is a simpler one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210003/how-can-i-nest-a-code-chunk-within-an-enumerate-environment-when-using-r-markdow

Comment: To clarify, you want to show the expression `x<-2+3` and `x`, but you do not want to evaluate either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found this: [How can I nest a code chunk within an enumerate environment when using R Markdown?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210003/how-can-i-nest-a-code-chunk-within-an-enumerate-environment-when-using-r-markdow), which inspires the following solution:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: monochrome
date: '2022-05-20'
header-includes:
- \newcommand{\benum}{\begin{enumerate}}
- \newcommand{\eenum}{\end{enumerate}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```

\benum

\item 

```{r}
x <- 2+3
x
```

\eenum
````

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need this? See here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-05-20'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```

```{=latex}

\begin{tabular}{ll}

x <- 2+3\\
x\\

\end{tabular}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @TarJae, for your answer. I have just updated my question, which by my fault, did not clarify the following: I want the R chunk to be both evaluated and its code shown.

Answer (score 2):

In any of the following examples, you can substitute a double return instead of `\\`.

If you are wanting to just show those expressions then do not put it in a code chunk:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-05-20'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
{
x <- 2 + 3\\x
}
\end{enumerate}
````

This will produce:

[image]

---

Otherwise, if you want to evaluate an inline expression use backticks and `r`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-05-20'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
{
`r x <- 2 + 3; x`
}
\end{enumerate}
````

Which produces:

[image]

---

Lastly, you can of course combine these two concepts to show the expression and evaluate the value by doing this:

```
x <- 2 + 3\\
`r x <- 2 + 3; x`
```

If your expression is more complex, I would recommend having the code chunk outside of your LaTeX for evaluation.

---

**Update**

For simpler expressions you could do something like:

````
```{r, include = F}
exprsn <- "x <- 2 + 3"
```

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
{
`r exprsn`\\
`r eval(parse(text = exprsn)); x`
}
\end{enumerate}
````

Comment: Thanks, @LMc, for your answer. I have just updated my question, which by my fault, did not clarify the following: I want the R chunk to be both evaluated and its code shown.