# How to plot an R graph within latex code in Rmarkdown pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

Trivial but annoying issue with Rmarkdown. I am trying to display landscape and portrait pages within the same pdf document from Rmarkdown.

I searched different solutions and decided to stick to the latex option ([R chunk inside LaTeX in an rmarkdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324034/r-chunk-inside-latex-in-an-rmarkdown-document)). However, even with that option I cannot manage to put R code within latex commands.

````
---
title: ""
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output: pdf_document
---


\newpage
\blandscape

```{r}
plot(1,1)
```
\elandscape

\newpage
More portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

I got an error:

```
output file: hello.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: \begin{landscape} on input line 113 ended by \end{document}.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile hello.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See hello.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

while the following code is working:

````
---
title: ""
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output: pdf_document
---


\newpage
\blandscape

```{r}
1+1
```
\elandscape

\newpage
More portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

I have no idea why :D

Does someone have one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining new commands, you can directly use the underlying commands of an environment:

````
---
title: ""
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
output: pdf_document
---


\newpage
\landscape

```{r}
plot(1,1)
```
\endlandscape

\newpage
More portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you understand why my commands were not working ?